# Nginx redirect 404 for profile image to gravitar

Tags: nginx, gravatar

On my site I'm hosting profile images for my users under "/foo/bar/images/`filename`" with `filename` being a md5 hash of the user's email address (like gravatar).

I'd like to configure my Nginx server to serve the those profile images at the path /images/profile/`filename`. However when the file doesn't exist, I want it to either redirect to http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/`filename` or be a proxy.

Is this possible in Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Nginx has a `rewrite` method that works perfectly.

```
location /images/profile {
   error_page 404 @missingImage;
}
location @missingImage {
   rewrite \images/prof\ile/([\w]+) http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$1;
}
```